# Django order by parent object with many to many relation with child object

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I have two models

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)

class Account(models.Model):
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name=account_courses)
```

I want to order by Course model by count of accounts

I have tried by creating a property method

```
@property
def course_accounts(self):
    return self.account_courses.count()
```

I am able to count the objects using this method but not able to order by objects using

`courses = Course.objects.all().order_by('course`*`accounts')`

It throws field error with: "Cannot resolve keyword 'course*account' into field"

Answer (score 1):

You can not order by a method or property, since the ordering happens at the database, and the database does not know anything about the Django models.

You work with a query that orders by an expression with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Course.objects.alias(naccount=Count('account_courses')).order_by('-naccount')
```